# What is uninitialized constant ApplicationHelper telling me?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting an `uninitialized constant ApplicationHelper` error, but I'm not exactly sure what it's telling me.

The Error;

```
uninitialized constant ApplicationHelper::IpsTcpHdr
Extracted source (around line #120):

117:                                             'icmp'
118:                                         end %></td>
119:         <td class='src_ip'><%= get_attacker_ip(event.sid, event.cid).to_s(16).rjust(8,'0').scan(/.{2}/).map(&:hex).join('.') %></td>
120:         <td class='src_port'><%= get_tcp_sport(event.sid, event.cid) %></td>
121:         <td class='tgt_ip'><%= get_target_ip(event.sid, event.cid).to_s(16).rjust(8,'0').scan(/.{2}/).map(&:hex).join('.') %></td>
122:         <td class='tgt_port'><%= 'tgt_port' %></td>
123:       </tr>
```

Here is the ApplicationHelper;

```
  def get_tcp_sport(sid,cid)
    IpsTcpHdr.where('sid =? and cid =?', sid, cid).first.tcp_sport
  end
```

Here is my IpsTcpHdr;

```
class IpsTcpHdr < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :sid, :cid, :tcp_sport, :tcp_dport, :tcp_seq, :tcp_ack, :tcp_off, :tcp_res, :tcp_flags, :tcp_win,
                  :tcp_csum, :tcp_urp
  self.primary_keys = :sid, :cid
  self.table_name = 'tcphdr'
  belongs_to :ips_ip_hdr
end
```

Here is what I'm calling in my view;

```
<td class='src_port'><%= get_tcp_sport(event.sid, event.cid) %></td>
```

Here is info from the database;

```
csdashboard=# SELECT * from tcphdr;
 sid | cid  | tcp_sport | tcp_dport |  tcp_seq   |  tcp_ack   | tcp_off | tcp_res | tcp_flags | tcp_win | tcp_csum | tcp_urp 
-----+------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+---------+----------+---------
   1 |    1 |     61667 |        80 |  239316451 | 3044404141 |       8 |       0 |        24 |    8208 |    63248 |       0
   1 |    2 |     61670 |        80 | 3279522000 | 4110870482 |       8 |       0 |        24 |    8208 |    34845 |       0
```

Comment: Looks like it is not able to recognize that `IpsTchHdr` is a model class. could you provide path to a file which contains `IpsTcpHdr` class?

Comment: It seems you haven't included the Application Helper in your controller and the view cannot find the method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What this is telling you is that ruby can't find the constant (class) IpsTcpHdr -- it is looking in ApplicationHelper.

You can resolve this by requiring (require '') the file that IpsTcpHdr is in. However you can also get rails to autoload files in some folders for you, however your file would have to be called ips_tcp_hdr.rb and located within a place where rails autoloads (e.g. app/models directory or (depending on rails and your config) lib/ directory).

Note that your question would be better posed as "What is uninitialized constant ApplicationHelper::SomeClassName telling me?"

Comment: Thanks much!! I was using `ips_tcphdr.rb` model, changed it to `ips_tcp_hdr.rb` and it worked!! Thanks again!